# proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 1260

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, plesk

I am working on Laravel 5.8 and PHP 7.2 and my code is working fine on cPanel Admin. But when I tried to upload it on a different domain with Plesk Admin then this error showed up.

> in Process.php line 334

Comment: Can you show your code here.

Comment: This is not a coding problem I think. (at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 1260) this is the problem.

Comment: Problem seems to be with PHP configurations of Plesk Admin.

Comment: $this->process = proc_open($commandline, $descriptors, $this->processPipes->pipes, $this->cwd, $envPairs, $options);

Comment: This line of code is causing error.